# c++ Floating point subtraction error and absolute values

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, subtraction, rounding-error

The way I understand it is: when subtracting two `double` numbers with double precision in c++ they are first transformed to a significand starting with one times 2 to the power of the exponent. Then one can get an error if the subtracted numbers have the same exponent and many of the same digits in the significand, leading to loss of precision. To test this for my code I wrote the following safe addition function:

```
double Sadd(double d1, double d2, int& report, double prec) {
    int exp1, exp2;
    double man1=frexp(d1, &exp1), man2=frexp(d2, &exp2);
    if(d1*d2<0) {
        if(exp1==exp2) {
            if(abs(man1+man2)<prec) {
                cout << "Floating point error" << endl;
                report=0;
            }
        }
    }
    return d1+d2;
}
```

However, testing this I notice something strange: it seems that the actual error (not whether the function reports error but the actual one resulting from the computation) seems to depend on the absolute values of the subtracted numbers and not just the number of equal digits in the significand...

For examples, using `1e-11` as the precision `prec` and subtracting the following numbers:

1) 9.8989898989898-9.8989898989897: The function reports error and I get the highly incorrect value 9.9475983006414e-14

2) 98989898989898-98989898989897: The function reports error but I get the correct value 1

Obviously I have misunderstood something. Any ideas?

Comment: If you wish to obtain not only an approximate result, but a bound on the error of a floating-point computation, you can use interval arithmetic, rounding downward for the lower bound and upward for the upper bound. There must be C++ packages to do exactly that readily available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you subtract two floating-point values that are nearly equal, the result will mostly reflect noise in the low bits. Nearly equal here is more than just same exponent and almost the same digits. For example, 1.0001 and 1.0000 are nearly equal, and subtracting them could be caught by a test like this. But 1.0000 and 0.9999 differ by exactly the same amount, and would not be caught by a test like this.

Further, this is **not** a safe addition function. Rather, it's a post-hoc check for a design/coding error. If you're subtracting two values that are so close together that noise matters you've made a mistake. Fix the mistake. I'm not objecting to using something like this as a debugging aid, but please call it something that implies that that's what it is, rather than suggesting that there's something inherently dangerous about floating-point addition. Further, putting the check inside the addition function seems excessive: an assert that the two values won't cause problems, followed by a plain old floating-point addition, would probably be better. After all, most of the additions in your code won't lead to problems, and you'd better know where the problem spots are; put asserts in the problems spots.

Comment: If you wrote “If you subtract two **approximate** floating-point values that are nearly equal, the result will mostly reflect noise in the low bits”, then no-one would quibble. The way you have written it, someone might point out that subtraction of two floating-point values that are nearly equal is an exact operation (Sterbenz lemma).

Comment: @PascalCuoq - I was deliberately a bit fuzzy because this is written for a beginner who would not benefit from a treatise on floating-point math.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks! I see now that I should have done this in a way using the binary values of the numbers instead. Do you agree that then the test would work, since then the significand always start with 1? For the name: you are right what I want is a tool for finding problems in the code; safe addition was the wrong choice of words.

Comment: @jorgen - there are lots of threads about what I somewhat contemptuously call "nearly equal"; those threads are about replacing `==` with fuzzy equality, which is not what you're suggesting here. But the coding in those threads is generally appropriate for a debugging aid. Essentially, if the difference divided by the smaller of the two numbers is less than some assumed precision, you've got nearly equal. (Yes, watch out for zero values when you divide) The important thing is that you can do this with ordinary floating-point math; you don't have to fiddle with bits.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah that's true, this way I can get a function that does what I wanted to do. I still don't understand though, why in this way 1000000000000-99999999999 and 1-0.99999999999 are different; both are "reported" by my function (depending on precision) but only the last actually gives wrong answer.

Comment: @jorgen: If you want to test for whether relative error may have increased due to a loss of absolute value, then you can simply test by comparing the magnitude of the result to the magnitude of either of the inputs. If the result is much lower in magnitude than an input, then the range of potential relative error is much greater in it than in the inputs (unless the errors in the two inputs are highly correlated for some reason). E.g., `r = d1+d2; if (fabs(r) < 0x1p-20 * fabs(d1)) std::cout << "Relative error may have increased by 0x1p20.\n";`.

Comment: @jorgen: Also, the preceding makes it clear that this issue has nothing to do with floating-point. It is pure math. If you have two values, d1 and d2 that may have any sort of error in them (calculation error, measurement error, sample error), and you calculate r = d1+d2, and r is much smaller in magnitude than d1 or d2, then the relative error in r is much greater than the relative error in d1 or d2. E.g., if d1 is 100 with 1% error and d2 is -100 with 1% error, then r is anything from -2 to 2, with potentially infinite relative error. No floating-point involved.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks! Yes you are right I am confusing the terms; I'm not talking about floating pt error, but the kind you are describing. However I'm still confused. consider this: when calculating 10000000000000.0-999999999999.0 and 1-0.999999999999 the answer divided by input is the same (10^-13) but still the latter gets an error when calculated while the former doesn't.

Comment: @jorgen: If you are asking why the code in your question behaves different for those two situations, observe that 10000000000000.0 and 999999999999.0 have the same power-of-two exponent (39 and 39) but 1 and 0.999999999999 do not (0 and -1). So the former fall into the `if (exp1 == exp2)` path but the latter do not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok I see! So in the end I can compare relative size of answer to inputs to estimate danger of error but it might not actually happen (false alarm)?

Comment: @jorgen: Yes. Typically, a person designing code knows that error may be up to some amount, but they do not know the actual amount. It is possible for errors to cancel out or be small even though there was a possibility for them to be large. Knowing that the result of an addition is smaller than its operands only tells you there is a possibility for much larger relative error; it does not tell you what the actual error is.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Pete Becker's answer.

Note that the problem of degenerated result might also occur with exp1!=exp2

For example, if you subtract

```
1.0-0.99999999999999
```

So,

```
bool degenerated =
       (epx1==exp2   && abs(d1+d2)<prec)
    || (epx1==exp2-1 && abs(d1+2*d2)<prec)
    || (epx1==exp2+1 && abs(2*d1+d2)<prec);
```

You can omit the check for d1*d2<0, or keep it to avoid the whole test otherwise...

If you want to also handle loss of precision with degenerated denormalized floats, that'll be a bit more involved (it's as if the significand had less bits).

Comment: Ok I see! Yeah the d1*d2 is there so I don't have to know the signs in complicated code, but I should put it a the beginning so everything is avoided otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to prove that for IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic, if x/2 <= y <= 2x then calculating x - y is an exact operation and will give the exact result correctly without any rounding error.

And if the result of an addition or subtraction is a denormalised number, then the result is *always* exact.